# Are shm and wal files needed when using an Encrypted CoreData implementation?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, encryption, encrypted-core-data-sql

I'm using an encrypted [CoreData framework](https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data) that was recommend.

I noticed that the shm and wal files are missing from the documents directory. 
I did some research and it seems like they are temporary files that the SQLite data base uses.

Are they removed for security reasons or did I do something wrong ?

Here is my persistent store coordinator from my CoreData Stack.

```
private lazy var psc: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    let coordinator = EncryptedStore.makeStore(self.managedObjectModel, passcode: "1Gd3-dflv19902-dfj")
    return coordinator
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

The shm and wal files are created and used only for some journaled modes of operation for the SQLite store, so it depends entirely on how the store is configured as to wether that are created. If they are created you can't just delete them as they are required and you'll corrupt the data store by doing so.